# php login always picking else

Tags: php, html

In my login check page it always goes to the else statement even if the text is right.

Signin page

```
<form method="post" action="login.php">
<input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username"><br>
<input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

loginin check page

```
<?php
session_start();
//connect to database
include("db.php");

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$q = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' ");
//row count
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($q);
if($numrows == 1){
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
$_SESSION["username"] = $row["username"]; 
$_SESSION["password"] = $row["password"];}header("location:check.php");}
//always going to this else statement
else
{header("location:wrong.php");}
?>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: can you confirm that `$numrows` is really returning `1`?

Comment: Try echoing `$username` and `$password` and compare them manually against the data in your table

Comment: $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($q); based on this you've check condition! so here the question for you is $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($q); returns 1 ?? Or print_r($_POST); and check the same with your database!

Comment: Please try to add exit() after header(), then recheck your scripts. And please make sure $numrows = 1.

Comment: I think that mysqli_num_rows($q); is not returning 1, try to dump it and see this output, by using var_dump(mysqli_num_rows($q)); or it may be the case it's returning value more than 1 , try replacing $numrows == 1 by $numrows >= 1. It must work in either case if your database is working fine !

Comment: Is that Okay @ShashankShah ?

Comment: Op will comment! even i'm waiting for his comment!

Comment: @SKG tried the  $numrows >= 1 it works thanks!

Comment: @DingoDile, I am happy to see it solved your problem. I am posting this as answer please accept and upvote my answer to show your thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that `mysqli_num_rows($q);` is not returning 1, try to dump it and see this output, by using `var_dump(mysqli_num_rows($q));` or it may be the case it's returning value more than 1 , try replacing `$numrows == 1` by `$numrows >= 1`.
It must work in either case if your database is working fine !

Comment: should be in comment!

Comment: @ShashankShah it solved OP's problem please remove your downvote to support me as well as OP, it will be grateful to you !

Comment: Ok, everyone please remove your downvotes,It will motivate me to provide my continuous effort to the forum, or if you'have any valid reason for that please share with all

Comment: Thank you very much @AmitChauhan. I don't know why people downvote the posts until they have any reason behind that, they are just misusing their powers

Comment: I used   if($numrows == true) in my code and that worked

Comment: $numrows returns an integer, when succeeds ! You shouldn't normally compare operands of different types, if you have some code that does this there is probably a mistake. The result may not make a lot of sense.

Comment: Ok i have copied that code from a site for a simple project. And now i am using different type of queries. now i am always using this type of query in my customised codeigniter '$sql = "SELECT * FROM `usr_profile` WHERE OathId = '$uid'";
        $result = $this->db->query($sql);
  $row = $this->db->fetchAll($result);
        if (sizeof($row)>0) {
            # User is already present
        }' so i don't have any idea about that. That's why i asked you

Comment: Nothing to worry about. Keep this in mind in future, so as to prevent software disasters

Comment: @RemyaR If you like my above answer, then you're welcome to upvote it !

Comment: Thanks for your effort and time. I am very happy to help you !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106359/discussion-between-skg-and-remya-r).

Answer (score -1):

```
$q = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' ");
```

`mysqli_query()` need `$connection` parameter resource from `mysqli_connect()`.

it must be:

```
$q = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' ");
```

also I suggest:

```
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($q);
if($numrows > 0) {
// ...
}
```

Comment: It is not required in the cases when only one connection  is established, It will automatically select the last made connection !

Comment: did u see the question. he using mysqli, with "i".

Comment: See the comment from OP ! It worked without this ! You shouldn't argue with people until you have some valid reason/proof. Please remove your above comment, otherwise I will have to report it to STO

Comment: @SKG BTW, `mysqli_query` **require** connection parameter.

Answer (score -4):

I think you are not passing correctly the password/username to the database, try to change:

```
$q = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' ");
```

by:

```
$q = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='" . $username . "' AND password='".$password."' ");
```

Comment: What's the difference between them?

Comment: $q = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' "); will work bro!